# what's faster: recreate or clear()?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a question about the performance of the std::vector<> in C++. Is it faster to reuse the same vector by calling its clear() method or it it faster to recreate the vector?

The following example is no real life code, it's only for making clear what the question is:

```
//Example ONE: is this faster
std::vector<int> foo;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    foo.clear();
    for(int j = 0; j < 100; ++j)
    {
        foo.push_back(i+j);
    }
}

//Example TWO: or is that faster?
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    std::vector<int> foo;
    for(int j = 0; j < 100; ++j)
    {
        foo.push_back(i+j);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't those things implementation dependent?

Comment: Profile it. Boooooring!

Comment: Yes, why all the downvotes?! So the OP doesn't know that calling `clear` on a vector doesn't have to free allocated memory. Last I checked, it's not a crime to not know something. If everyone on SO knew all there is to know about programming we wouldn't need this website, would we?

Comment: @Praetorian: I think the downvotes are pretty much automated in the behavior of people for questions about *performance* where the actual *usage pattern* is not explained. Consider for example, that the `vector` was *copied* to a different place after all the `push_backs` and before the next iteration, then all the answers suggesting `clear()` as a better alternative might be wrong, and the fastest thing could be *moving* (either C++0x *move semantics* or `swap`)... Asking about performance without context does not make sense.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: I get what you're saying, but it could also just be idle curiosity that prompted this question. IMHO, not having a concrete use case doesn't automatically make it too unworthy a question to be asked on SO.

Comment: @Praetorian... don't ask me, I did not downvote :) I tend to make the downvotes explicit with a comment on why I downvoted, so that it serves two purposes: make the question less important in the ranking and allow the questioner to learn and make better questions in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `clear()` cannot by its contract deallocate the `vector` memory, instead just sets the internal "size" flag to `0`, so that method will be faster.

Comment: More than "slightly", I'd say.

Comment: I don't know of any implementation that releases the memory.

Comment: @David: Creating a new vector does! :D [edit: yes, ok, letting the old one die does]

Comment: `std::vector<>::clear()` is not allowed to free the memory, since one of its post-conditions is that `capacity()` is unchanged.

Comment: Then it's not implementation dependant (I didn't look at the `vector` documentation).  Edited.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the implementation of `std::vector` in the C++ standard library that you're using, but it is likely that the first case will be faster because most implementations do not actually free allocated memory when you call `std::vector::clear`. So the first one does not perform repeated allocations once the inner loop has been executed the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. No. The first one is faster, probably. It depends. The only useful answer comes from you profiling your own code in your own environment.

Try profiling your code to see what happens. Compiling [your program at ideone](http://ideone.com/NA9v4) reveals that, for one particular compiler/os/machine/run,  your first example is 4x faster.

And [this program](http://ideone.com/pfhqH) shows an intermediate solution, which goes faster than #2, slower than #1, for this particular compiler/os/machine/run.

Answer (score 0):

Example 2 has repeated heap allocations for the array inside of std::vector.  Example 1 is faster because it avoids repeatedly allocating memory on the heap unless the vector needs to be resized internally.

Comment: `s/allocating memory on the heap/dynamically-allocating memory/`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to run benchmarks for your compiler. The `clear()` and 'allocate' methods are implementation-dependent.

Comment: That the capacity of a vector never shrinks is not implementation-dependent at all. [edit: though C++11 _does_ have `shrink_to_fit`]

Comment: @Tomalak: I was actually thinking about it. There is no specific clause in the standard that inhibits the implementation from actually freeing the memory. A vector that *shrinks* would be harder to implement in many cases (while maintaining the *amortized constant time* cost of `push_back`), but I don't think it would be *impossible*, and that for the general case of `erase`, with the specifics of `clear()` I don't see any reason why a conforming implementation could not release the memory (then again, I have not gone over the standard looking for this particular case...)

Comment: @David: I've been going over it too. I can't see any guarantee that `clear` *must* invoke `reserve`. It seems quite strongly implied to me, but it's not stated.

Comment: @Tomalak: true it never shrinks, but I worked on an embedded system where the vector could move from 'fast ram' to 'slow ram' depending on what you were doing.  `clear() would not move it but writes would.

Answer (score 0):

To both clear a vector and reduce its capacity to your implementation's minimum, [Scott Meyers](http://bit.ly/qHpx5y) recommends the **swap trick**:

```
std::vector<int>().swap( foo );
```

It would also be faster than iterating through the vector with a hand-rolled loop to restore its contents.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, the reuse case will probably be faster on most machines. You are storing primitive data that don't need destruction (or even have a destructor). On the other hand, if the vector contains non-POD objects, each element will be destroyed by the call to `clear`. On the third hand, all of the accumulated data will need to be destructed eventually.